# SSIS Lookup Transformation Data Type issue

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

We are using SSIS with Visual Studio 2012, and Oracle 11 database.
We have a Lookup Transformation from a Flat File to a result from the Oracle database View (Use result of an SQL Query).
The query is something like this:

```
With A AS 
(select … as AType,
Trim(vw.AID) as  AID
from mySchedume.myView_vw vw 
) 
Select * from A where  AID  is not NULL and AType is not null
```

In the Lookup Transformation Editor > Columns, there is a link between `InputColumnC` (Available Input Column) to AID (Available Lookup Column).

On other people’s machines (Windows 7), when I hover on both columns on Lookup Transformation Editor > Column, they are of data type `DT_STR`, and there is a link between `InputColumnC` (Available Input Column) to `AID` (Available Lookup Column).

But, when I do that on my machine (Windows 10), AID is of data type `DT_WSTR`, and there is no link between `InputColumnC` (Available Input Column) to `AID` (Available Lookup Column). When I try to link the 2 columns, it says

> Cannot map the input column, ‘InputColumnC’, to the lookup column, ‘AID’ because the data types do not match.

Why `AID` has data type `DT_STR` on a Windows 7 machines, but it has a data type of `DT_WSTR` on my machine ?

How can I fix this issue ?
I don't want to add a Derived Column, since it is working in other people's machines (Windows 7).

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming that the developers on Win 7 and you are using the *exact* same query in the Lookup and the same database, then I would suggest you confirm that you're working with the same version of your Oracle driver/provider.

Comment: Yes, exact same code with same query in the Lookup and same database. How can I check what version of Oracle driver/provider we are using ?

Comment: AID in Oracle is Char(100).
Since our Oracle is version 11, do I need to use Oracle Provider for OLE DB version 11 (not 12) ?
And, do I need to use the 32 bit version of the Provider ?

Thank you